# Extracting part of shapefile

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes

I try to download data from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe for UK. I downloaded England, Wales and Scotland shapefiles. I have also Ireland and Northern Ireland shapefile (http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/ireland-and-northern-ireland.html) but I don't know how to cut them to obtain only Northern Ireland.

Attributes of all shapefiles (England, Wales and Scotland, Ireland and Northern Ireland) look like:

[image: attributes].

Can someone help me?

Comment: in the Ireland Download open the gis_osm_places_a_free_1.shp in QGIS. Select by Attribute fclass='county' and name = County Armagh  the list is short https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counties_of_Northern_Ireland#/media/File:Northern_Ireland_-_Counties.png save selected as will get you the data then you can clip using that polygon file

Comment: @Mapperz I forgot to add that I am rely on gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.shp. I want to extract from them fclass="park" for England, Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland (I will do this in R, I am new in QGIS and I have problem with extracting Northern Ireland). Is it possible in gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.shp? How can I do clipping?

Comment: Spatial create the Counties and clip the ireland data that is the only way using that data.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own post. Instead, [Edit] the question to contain your update.

Comment: See here for answers to similar questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/401021/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/398093/88814

Answer (score 1):

If I have really understood your question.if u have both Northern and southern Ireland in same shapefile, just click that in layers list then go up there and select features a partly yellow button...it after clicking, select Northern ireland shape it will turn yellow. Then right click on the same shapefile on layers list and save as.....name as u want chose directory and save...it will again change color. Uncheck all the other layers and remain with Northern ireland.. hope that's what u wanted...