# Seeking detailed Cyprus borders shapefile

Tags: shapefile, vector, data, borders, cyprus

I need to to show the Republic of Cyprus, the TRNC, the Buffer Zone and the British Bases.

I've looked everywhere and every time it only shows the Republic, which makes sense as it is the UN recognised one but I need all of them.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded the data from OpenStreetMap as described below. Find it [here to downlaod](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/OhpItbwJ3lO6oWr): QGIS project with polygons for the areas you're interested in. See below for details.

[image]

**How it can be done**

Download the different borders separately from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) (always a great resource from where to get free geodata!) to get a separate layer for each unit: see the links below. You can use [OverpassTurbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) for that: [see here for a detailed description](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368774/88814) of how to do that. Than you have to clip one layer from the other [as described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398170/88814) - probably including the coastline to represent only the inland + islands (for mainland Cyprus without island, see the last linked OSM-relation).

Find here the map data for the different borders you're looking for:

- Republic of Cyprus:
  https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/307787
- British Sovereign Base Areas:
  https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3263728
- North Cyprus (TRNC):
  https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2514541
- Buffer zone: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3263909
- Mainland Cyprus (without islands, sea): https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3263732

To get only the inland area of the two political entities (Republic of Cyprus and TRNC), use the query `admin_level=5` in overpass turbo as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

Than export / save the result and load the result to QGIS. Save it as GeoPackage file. Select the features representing the republic, toggle editing and [`Merge Selected Features`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=merge%20selected%20features#merge-selected-features), see next screenshot:

[image]